# Redirecting CMD Commands To An EXE File

Tags: batch-file, redirect, cmd, command, internal

Basically I have created an choice batch that every so often I can archive the contents of my boot data since I change it quite often and it works absolutely perfect, however I face the problem that every time I compile the batch from .BAT to.EXE with Advanced BAT to EXE converter the command 'bcdedit' never works and says “Not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.”
Now the first thing I did was to make sure if I had the environment variables directed on my hard drive and it seemed fine:

`Path: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Users\Support\DOCUME~1\MYFILE~1\Programs\SYSTEM~1\DISKEE~1\`

It has all the variables needed to work perfectly plus a few external ones which is ok then I thought that maybe I should try to make it direct on my folder, by doing some research I found on another forum:
[Setting or Modifying a System Wide Environment Variable In CMD.EXE](https://superuser.com/questions/65816/setting-or-modifying-a-system-wide-environment-variable-in-cmd-exe)
I made a separate .BAT and I called it and it seems it did create the separate variable:

> C:\Users\???\Documents\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Users\Support\DOCUME~1\MYFILE~1\Programs\SYSTEM~1\DISKEE~1" /f

But It Still Didn't Work!

I read upon another form:

[Syswow64 Redirection](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t686141-syswow64-redirection-for-cmd-exe.html)

The person solution was to use Create Process () to create a program that automatically redirects him to the folder using sysnative (System32) but I'm a total beginner at C#, CMD is my strongest area when it comes to coding.

Please please I beg of you to help me as soon as possible and if you do have an answer please state in the easiest way possible and why. Here's my script just in case:

```
    :START
echo.
echo Call apath.bat
echo.
echo.
echo (E) - Start Process.
echo (C) - Launch Part 2 Of Process.
echo (N) - Load NoDrives Manager.
echo (D) - Display Currect Account and Computer Information
echo (X) - Exit EDIM.
echo.
echo NOTE - It will not work if not started with Admin Privillages.
echo.
:Choice
set/p Option=Please enter your option: 
if '%Option%' == 'E' goto :Incognito
if '%Option%' == 'C' goto :Touch
if '%Option%' == 'N' goto :Manager
if '%Option%' == 'D' goto :Data
if '%Option%' == 'X' goto :Exit
echo.
echo.
echo Invalid Option - Please Reselect.
goto :Choice
:RetryE
Echo An Error was found!
set/p RetryE=Retry? Y/N: 
if '%RetryE%' == 'Y' goto :Incognito
if '%RetryE%' == 'N' goto :Exit
:Incognito
Timeout 5
echo.
echo.
echo.
Echo Saving OriginalBCD...
bcdedit /export "Data/BCD/OriginalBCD"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 goto :RetryE
IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 0 goto :RetryE
Echo Checking presence of BCD...
IF NOT EXIST "Data/BCD/OriginalBCD" goto :RetryE
Echo Deleting Boot Entry...
bcdedit /delete {current}
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 goto :RetryE
IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 0 goto :RetryE
Echo Saving EditedBCD...
bcdedit /export "Data/BCD/IncogBCD"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 goto :RetryE
IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 0 goto :RetryE
Echo Checking presence of BCD...
IF NOT EXIST "Data/BCD/IncogBCD" goto :RetryE
Echo Allowing User Control For Assigning System Reserved Partitions...
Echo -Commands-
Echo Diskpart
Echo List volume
Echo Select Volume "" (The one that has no Letter and remember number)
Echo Assign Letter=Z
Echo Select Volume "" (The one that has Letter E and remember number)
Echo Remove Letter=E  (This is the new system reserved partition)
Echo Then exit Diskpart to finish Part 1.
Diskpart
Echo Ready To Restart!
Timeout 5
Shutdown /r /t 30 
Goto :Start
:RetryC
set/p RetryE=Retry? Y/N: 
if '%RetryC%' == 'Y' goto :Touch
if '%RetryC%' == 'N' goto :Exit
:Touch
echo.
echo.
echo.
Echo Loading NDM...
Echo NOTE - Store the password somewhere safe!!!
Start "" "Data/NDM.exe"
Echo Loading EditedBCD...
bcdedit /import "Data/BCD/IncogBCD"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 goto :RetryC
IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 0 goto :RetryC
Echo Process Complete!
Timeout 5
Echo Returning to menu...
goto :Start
:Manager
echo.
Echo NOTE - Store the password somewhere safe!!!
Start "" /WAIT "Data/ndm.exe" 
Echo Returning to Menu...
goto :Start
:Data
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Processing Data...
Systeminfo
diskpart /s "Data/discpart.txt"
Echo Returning to Menu...
goto :Start
:Exit
Exit
```

Thanks So Much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bcdedit` is on the path by default so unless you are reusing the `PATH` variable then the problem is in the batch compiler.

You can test this by using the plain batch file - and if it works then you know where the problem is.

Comment: Oh, I never realized that BCDedit was on path by default, Thanks.