# Making Any Command in CMD work in a .BAT as an .EXE

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe

[Redirecting CMD Commands To An EXE File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366490/redirecting-cmd-commands-to-an-exe-file)

Long story short, basically I have the problem that every time I run BCDedit on the .BAT that I converted into an .EXE it never worked and I thought that the reason why it wasn't work was because it wasn't on `Path` but my Path was fine and even if it was on `Path` is set by default thanks to foxidrive.

Now my main problem is that is there a way I can convert it to an .EXE file with every single command working, is there a technique I could use to get BCDedit working as an .EXE file?

All of the commands do work it just BCDedit and I say if every single command would work so if somebody has a similar command problem like me they know how to figure it out, it works perfectly as batch but is there a way I can convert it and make BCDedit still work as an .EXE?

Please answer As Soon As Possible and if you want to take a look at my `Path` and Batch the visit the link at the top.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Compile this batch file and see if it works:

```
@echo off
bcdedit /?
pause
```

Then try this version:

```
@echo off
c:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /?
pause
```

Comment: Nope, BCDedit is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: See my edited answer.  Make sure that you do have a copy of `BCDedit.exe` in `c:\Windows\System32`

Comment: Still No Luck. I have BCDedit.exe in c:\Windows\System32 but when I try you edited answer its not recognized.

Comment: http://www.f2ko.de  <--- I tried the batch compiler here (32 bit one - there is a 64 bit one too) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the [SysWow64 Redirection](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t686141-syswow64-redirection-for-cmd-exe.html) link you listed states.  If you want a x86 application to call the 64-bit system directory you need to call the bcdedit application as follows.

```
%SystemRoot%\SysNative\bcdedit
```

This is because of Windows backwards compatibility measures, it is looking at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` instead of `C:\Windows\System32`.  Another alternative would be to compile the script as both x86 and 64-bit, but then you could only use each on the respective systems.

#### Update for Comments

Even though the path is correct, an x86 application will execute commands or batch scripts against the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` which will cause the path redirection issue.  Example to illustrate my point. On a 64-bit version of Windows, open `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and using Windows explorer create two unique files , one is `C:\Windows\System32\unique_test64.txt` and the other in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\unique_test86.txt`. Now on the x86 command prompt enter `if exist C:\Windows\System32\unique_test86.txt echo true`.  You will see that it is being redirected to SysWOW64 and will print true.  And if you enter `if exist C:\Windows\System32\unique_test64.txt echo true`, nothing will be found.

Screenshot Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB1tU.png

Comment: It should be on the path in a 64 bit system as well though, correct?  The batch compiler fails to find it according to the OP.  It seems to be the batch compiler issue.